# 'getAsync' returns 'Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync is not a function'

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm currently researching the Microsoft documentation for Outlook add-ins using the Javascript API and downloaded one of the samples provided by Microsoft, specifically the 'outlook-add-in-command-demo' from [Github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo).

I then modified `FunctionFile\Function.js` ([file](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/blob/master/FunctionFile/Functions.js)) on line **61** just before `event.completed();` and added the following:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.replaceAsync(
    'Hello world!', 
    { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Text }, 
    function callback(result) {

    });
```

This bit of code comes from the API documentation itself `replaceAsync` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#getasync-coerciontype--options--callback-))

When testing the add-in functionality I get the following error on the Developer Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Office.context.mailbox.item.body.replaceAsync is
>   not a function
>       at Object.getSubject [as callback] (Functions.js:62)
>       at outlook-web-16.01.js:16

Line **53** of the same file includes a similar call to the Office API and this one works without a problem (`var subject = Office.context.mailbox.item.subject;`). But `replaceAsync`, `getAsync`, `setAsync` and others just produce the same error.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you looked if you Outlook client/Exchange server are supporting the methods ? E.g. If using Exchange server 2013 you are limited to API methods from 1.1.

Comment: Office.context.mailbox.item.subject is a read API. If that works, you're probably trying to use a compose mode API in read mode. body.replaceAsync() and body.setAsync() do not work in mail read. Can you confirm that you are trying these APIs in compose mode?

Could you also provide the code you used for body.getAsync(...)? That should work.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I'm trying these methods on mail read. I want to build an add-in to parse the body of a message. Don't really need the add-in to do anything on compose mode.

Comment: body.replaceAsync() and body.setAsync() are not available on mail read, i.e., you cannot modify the email body in read mode. However, body.getAsync() should work. Could you confirm whether it does? A code snippet would also be helpful.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT yeah, that's totally the case. `getAsync()` works ok. Also, I just should've paid more attention to the docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.Body?view=outlook-js-preview) as the methods clearly specify Read or Compose modes. Thanks for your help. Just one last... what I want to do is parse an email body that is entirely encoded. I now know I cant just turn the body into a readable table and I'm left with the option of shoring the parsed data on a sidepane, the problem is, side pane is quite narrow, is there a way of showing a popup

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT ^ just to continue my idea up there. ...a popup with a data table of the parsed content. I tried jQuery UI for popup/modal but they only exist within the side pane.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to display a table as a popup. You can try using the [displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=word-js-preview#displaydialogasync-startaddress--options--callback-) API - it can open a URL in a new window. However, you will need to push the table to the backend and make a new URL.

It's better to ask this as a new question. Can you confirm that the original issue is fixed?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The original issue is fixed yes, please feel free to submit a replay so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office.context.mailbox.item.subject is a read API. If that works, you're probably trying to use a compose mode API in read mode. body.replaceAsync() and body.setAsync() do not work in mail read. Can you confirm that you are trying these APIs in compose mode? Could you also provide the code you used for body.getAsync(...)? That should work.